# getting error ==>`newline or ;' unexpected

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ksh

I am using ksh shell,when trying to combine commands ,i am getting below error.Any solution for it?

```
sleep 10 &;echo no
ksh: syntax error: `newline or ;' unexpected
```

However ,when i remove "&" it works.But as per my requirement ,i need to run first command and not wait for its output and proceed with next command.

Comment: `sleep 10 &` seems odd.  It means a separate process is sleeping which has no effect on the rest of your script.

Comment: [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) automatically points out [this](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC1045) and other common shell scripting issues.

Answer (score 3):

`&` itself is a command terminator, just like `;`. By using both, you are telling the shell to run `sleep 10` in the background, then run an "empty command", then run `echo no`. The shell, however, doesn't allow an empty command.

What you want is

```
sleep 10 & echo no
```